# Space between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to check that there are at least two words in my input field.

I tried this:

`var spaceReg =  /^\w+\s\w+$/`

It works fine but if I have three or more words, not anymore (or if I have a word like this meyer-miller).

My next try was this:

`/^(?:[\w-]+ ?)*$/`

but this works also if I have a space at the end of the first word and with single words.

Is there an expert here for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I originally thought you wanted words separated by dash to match.. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/YbWYp/8/

```
var spaceReg =  /[\-\w]+\s[\-\w]+/
```

EDIT: also, if you just want to make sure that you have some space within some non-space somewhere in your string you are testing, you could do something as simple as: http://jsfiddle.net/YbWYp/10/

```
var pattern = /\S\s\S/
```

Comment: thats great it works fine. just to make it perfect. if have have two or more spaces between the words, how i get it to work?

Comment: add a + after the \s, `/[\-\w]+\s+[\-\w]+/`, the + means "one or more", a * would mean "0 or more"

Comment: just know that it will match more than just word characters and dashes.. and again if you want more than 1 space to be accepted you'll have to add the `+` like `/\S\s+\S/`

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't add the start and end of string markers :

```
var spaceReg =  /\w\s+\w/
```

If you also want to ensure you have nothing else than words and spaces, then you can use

```
var spaceReg =  /^\w+\s+\w[\w\s]*$/
```

If you want to allow spaces at start (not sure from your question) and dash (from the comments), use

```
var spaceReg =  /^\s*[\w-]+\s+[\w-][\w-\s]*$/
```

Comment: You could even ditch the `+` quantifiers.

Comment: `/\w\s*\w/` to support multiple spaces

Comment: sorry, this is passing to:  meyer-miller. and thats not two words

Comment: @hamburger What do you mean ? I just tested `/^\w+\s+\w[\w\s]*$/.test('meyer-miller')` and got false.

Comment: if you test "meyer-miller nextname" it shout pass but it is also false

Comment: Oh, you want to allow dash. That wasn't in your first regex. So use `/^\s*[\w-]+\s+[\w-][\w-\s]*$/`.

Comment: It's not `*$`, it's `[\w-\s]*` (as many characters in `[\w-\s]` as you want) followed by the end of string marker (`$`).

Comment: I'am using also this: /^([a-zA-ZüÜäÄöÖéèàçâß\-\'\.\s]{3,64})*$/; then the * is wrong?

Comment: @hamburger, in your regex above it is checking for "zero or more" instances of groupings of 3 to 64 of any of those characters... although there doesn't appear to be anything that might separate those 3-64 char groupings

Comment: it shout check only that at least 3 char and max 64 are given. in my script it works fine but it seems to be wrong than ...

Comment: I imagine without the `()*` would work as well, not sure what it is there for as there is nothing else in the regex that might separate your expected characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.8.7 :004 > "asd asdasd "=~ /\w+(\s\w+)+/ 
 => 0 
1.8.7 :005 > "asd asdasd"=~ /\w+(\s\w+)+/ 
 => 0 
1.8.7 :006 > "asd asdasd asd"=~ /\w+(\s\w+)+/ 
 => 0 
1.8.7 :007 > "asd"=~ /\w+(\s\w+)+/
```

You can add * at the right side of \s to support multiple spaces